# Comparing Object attribute to string won't work

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to search a sorted list of objects and compare user input to the name value of those objects but it will say that the name being compared does not exist within one of the objects in the list.

I have so far tried using

```
for network in foundNetworks:
    if network.name == userInputName:
    print("found!")
    break
```

and

```
if any(network.name == networkName for network in foundNetworks):
    break
else:
    print("Invalid network name!")
```

The code I am using for sorting and creating networks:

```
    class Network():
        # init function must be like this
        def __init__(self, name, security, signalStrength):
            self.name = str(name)
            self.security = str(security)
            self.signalStrength = int(signalStrength)

            # passwords, credit card info etc.
            loot = set()

    # assume multiple new networks are created with varying names which are not the same
    newNetwork = Network(networkName, securityType, networkStrength)
    foundNetworks.append(newNetwork)


    # sort network based on signal strength
    foundNetworks = sorted(foundNetworks, key=lambda network: network.signalStrength, reverse=True)
```

## Update

Here is how I actually get user input and verify it exists.

```
import time
import linecache
from random import randint


def exampleCheck():
    class Network():
        # init function must be like this
        def __init__(self, name, security, signalStrength):
            self.name = str(name)
            self.security = str(security)
            self.signalStrength = int(signalStrength)


    foundNetworks = []
    securityTypes = ["Joe-Level-Encryption", "AES", "WPA2", "TKIP", "None", "Basic Encryption"]

    for i in range(10):
        while True:
            # uses linecache to randomly pick a name from networks.txt
            networkName = linecache.getline("networks.txt", randint(1, 19))
            networkName = networkName.replace('\n','')

            # ensure network name has not already been found before
            if any(network for network in foundNetworks if network.name == networkName):
                continue
            else:
                break

        # set random network strength and security type
        securityType = securityTypes[randint(0, 5)]
        networkStrength = randint(89, 1005)           

        # create a new network and store it in found networks
        newNetwork = Network(networkName, securityType, networkStrength)
        foundNetworks.append(newNetwork)


    # sort network based on signal strength
    foundNetworks = sorted(foundNetworks, key=lambda network: network.signalStrength, reverse=True)

    # display found networks
    for network in foundNetworks:
        print(network.name)

    while True:
        networkName = input("\nNETWORK TO TARGET >> ")
        if any(network.name == networkName for network in foundNetworks):
            print("Found!")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid network name!")

def main():
    exampleCheck()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

```
fbiSurveillance                       
cant get me
SBEGA 42932    
ppsadminlogin
notTorenting
notFakeW1f1
ppsWifi
mi network                        
unhakavle                       
coporateDominion

NETWORK TO TARGET >> mi network
Invalid network name!

NETWORK TO TARGET >>
```

### Expected Output

```
fbiSurveillance                       
cant get me
SBEGA 42932    
ppsadminlogin
notTorenting
notFakeW1f1
ppsWifi
mi network                        
unhakavle                       
coporateDominion

NETWORK TO TARGET >> mi network
Found!

NETWORK TO TARGET >>
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. Indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: Provide a concrete list in which the name you claim to be searching is not found in a reproducible manner.

Comment: See if you can reproduce this with just a list of strings. I am betting dollars to doughnuts you are expecting a case-insensitive comparison, but I can't help you if you don't provide any of the actually relevant info.

Comment: How are you getting the user input?

Comment: @mhawke Through input()

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated everything to hopefully clear your questions up/

Comment: Replace the loop with `print(network.name)` with `print(repr(network.name))`. I bet that will clear things up.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `networks.txt` file contains trailing whitespace for several of the network names, e.g. (quotes added for emphasis):

```
"fbiSurveillance                       "
"SBEGA 42932    "
"mi network                        "
"unhakavle                       "
```

The code takes the trouble to remove the newline character at the end of each line, but it would be better to strip off all trailing whitespace. You can use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20rstrip#str.rstrip) for that:

```
networkName = networkName.rstrip()
```

This will remove the extra spaces and the newline character, and it should fix the problem.

Comment: it is still saying the network isn't found. Do you think this could be some other issue?

Comment: Did you modify the code or the input file. Once I call `rstrip()` on each input line it works for me so, unless there is something different about the input, it should also work for you.

Comment: Your right! I did accidentally modify something. Thank you for helping me out with this :D

Comment: @Inviss: no worries.